# C++: bug disappears when try/catch added to code

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I have encountered a very strange error that maybe somebody can help me make sense of.  I have a code that crashes quite consistently with vector out of range error.  Another odd thing about this error is that when I toss in lots of cout statements throughout the code to try to pin down the location of the error, it stops crashing.

Anyways, as a further test, I put try/catch blocks around parts of the code, my implementation is something like:

```
try {
    // my code that is presumably causing problems
  }
  catch (out_of_range& oor) {
    cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << endl;
  }
```

When I add in this code, the bug seems to go away.  There are no more crashes, and I never see the cerr message in the catch.

Is there any possible way this can make sense?

Comment: I've found that when bugs "disappear" when observed, it's usually because I'm using an uninitialized variable. The extra code moves the memory location just enough to stop the crashing.

Comment: Changing behaviour when being observed? Must be quantum mechanics acting up again.

Comment: Bump up the warning level, the compiler may catch uninitialized variables use and some other things.

Comment: You may also be looking at a race condition if you are accessing a vector shared between threads. Hard to tell with such a small snippet.

Comment: No, single threaded application running on static data files, unlikely to be a race condition.

Comment: @chris It's a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)!

Comment: Have your run it through your debugger? Have you run it through valgrind? If you haven't done both of these ... then you should. If you have .. what did you see?

Comment: Just to update, the comment by Mark S. is indeed correct, it was an uninitialized loop index, found by bumping up the compiler warning level as suggested by Alexey.  Thanks for all the help and suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Step through old code in debugger and isolate error.  Step through new code in a debugger and isolate non-error.  I'm posting this as an "answer" and not a comment because it will give you the answer you are looking for in less time than it will take us to answer or you to read our answers.

Debugger in ten words: compile with -g, google "gdb cheatsheet", it's very simple.

Comment: It's interesting that you counted the contraction *it's* as two words.  That or you counted the ndash and 'g' in *-g* as two separate words..

Comment: cheatsheet is 2 words, but the space is omitted in case an old version of Google is being used.  gdb is 2 words, in which db is the word "debugger" and g is the word "gnu", in which g is 3 words because it means "gnu's not Unix", in which not is 1 word and Unix is 1 word but gnu's is 3 words (because the contraction doesn't add a word for "is"), and now in those 3 words gnu's gets a Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Windowsprogrammer: what would you know, you're a Windows programmer. *ducks*

Comment: Windows programmers know how to overflow stacks. Some of us even know how to kill guard pages.